Big Mac Index and PPP on the example with apple price
I calculated Big Mac Index for USD/RUB and obtained that RUB is undervalued approximately 40%.
It is explained by the fact that in Russia we have low labor costs.
I also calculated exchange rate on the example with apple price. I choosed apple price in USA and in Russia and obtain the same result - RUB is undervalued approximately 40%.
My question is: if the salaries in Russia will be raised then we will have that current exchange rate 1USD=88RUB corresponds PPP. But if we calculate again exchange rate on the example with apple price we obtain that RUB is undervalued 40% again.
How is it possible? Where did I go wrong?
Thanks!
